# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to convert a scilab code to python
I have the following code:

```
for ( i = 0:roi_sx:imgg_sx-roi_sx)
    for ( j = 0:roi_sy:imgg_sy-roi_sy)
        intensity = 0;
        for ( m = i+1:1:i+roi_sx )
            for ( n = j+1:1:j+roi_sy )
              intensity = intensity + imgg(m,n);  
              
            end
        end
        if ( intensity < threshold*roi_sx*roi_sy ) then
            imgs(i+1:1:i+roi_sx, j+1:1:j+roi_sy) = zeros(roi_sx, roi_sy);
        end
    end
end
```

this is what I could come up with:

```
for i in range(0,imgg_sx-roi_sx,roi_sx):
    for j in (0,imgg_sy-roi_sy,roi_sy):
        intensity = 0
        for m in range (i+1,i+roi_sx,1):
            for n in range (j+1,j+roi_sy,1):
              intensity = intensity + (imggmatrix[m][n])
        if intensity < threshold*roi_sx*roi_sy:
            imgs([i+1 for i in range(i+roi_sx)],[j+1 for j in range(j+roi_sx)]) = np.zeros((roi_sx, roi_sy),dtype=float)
            #np.imgs([i+1 for i in range(i+roi_sx)],[j+1 for j in range(j+roi_sx)]) = np.zeros((roi_sx, roi_sy),dtype=float)
```

anyone can please help me figure out what is wrong with this line, I appreciate every contribution

```
imgs([i+1 for i in range(i+roi_sx)],[j+1 for j in range(j+roi_sx)]) = np.zeros((roi_sx, roi_sy),dtype=float)
```

I got the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\medyo\Desktop\MIP\DataMatrix\DataMatrix.py", line 26, in <module>
    imgs([i+1 for i in range(i+roi_sx)],[j+1 for j in range(j+roi_sx)])
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: The "if statement" ```if intensity < threshold*roi_sx*roi_sy:``` at its current location will always see ```intensity = 0```. It should be indented under the "for loop".

Comment: Assuming imgs is a np.array, you should use double square brackets: ’imgs[[.…], [...]] = ...’

Comment: Also, there is a missing ’range’ in ’for j in (...):’ I believe

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. google the error. don't just post a question without research. also learn python syntax. round parentheses are _calls_, not indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it, but from what I see your code should be like this since The "if statement" `if intensity < threshold*roi_sx*roi_sy:` at its current location will always see `intensity = 0`. It should be indented under the "for loop".

```
for i in range(0,imgg_sx-roi_sx,roi_sx):
    for j in (0,imgg_sy-roi_sy,roi_sy):
        intensity = 0
        for m in range (i+1,i+roi_sx,1):
            for n in range (j+1,j+roi_sy,1):
              intensity = intensity + (imggmatrix[m][n])
              if intensity < threshold*roi_sx*roi_sy:
                imgs([i+1 for i in range(i+roi_sx)],[j+1 for j in range(j+roi_sx)]) = np.zeros((roi_sx, roi_sy),dtype=float)
                #np.imgs([i+1 for i in range(i+roi_sx)],[j+1 for j in range(j+roi_sx)]) = np.zeros((roi_sx, roi_sy),dtype=float)
```